# 403 Access Not Configured

Tags: php

I'm using Google custom search API. It worked fine for a couple of days, but now I get this error message:

> Array ( [error] => Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [domain]
>   => usageLimits [reason] => accessNotConfigured [message] => Access Not Configured.  The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a
>   per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the
>   request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google
>   Developers Console to update your configuration. [extendedHelp] =>
>   https://console.developers.google.com ) ) [code] => 403 [message] =>
>   Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or
>   there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API
>   key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the
>   Google Developers Console to update your configuration. ) )

The API is of course enabled. Quota is not exceeded.
My servers IP address is listed in key settings.
Everything works fine in the API Explorer.

I cant figure out why it suddenly stopped working?

Comment: Have you change the URL of your project

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved: I removed my servers IP address in the "credentials" settings (making any IP allowed). This worked. Then I put my servers IP adress back in. Its still working. Must have been some strange hiccup at Google related to IP settings.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this when I changed the IP address on my server.  In the Google Developer's Console I simply changed the IP address in

APIs & auth -> Credentials - > Server key -> Accept requests from these IP servers